Power bi matrix is repeating headers
I have a Dimension table with the following data:



ID_Site
Site
Site corrected




1
Site1
Site1


2
Site2
Site2


3
Site3
Site3


4
Site4
Site3


5
Site5
Site4


6
Site6
Site4



This table has a relationship with another table using the Site_ID column.
I have now created a matrix with the following fields:

Rows: Team (Column from another table)
Columns : Site corrected
Values: Count of ticket number

What I expect to get is the values for Site3 and Site4 aggregated:



Team
Site1
Site2
Site3
Site4




Team1
2
4
16
11


Team2
5
8
13
14


Team3
1
4
16
12


Team4
1
9
11
16



What I'm getting is the Site3 and Site4 header twice with the ticket count of Site instead of Site corrected (aggregated)



Team
Site1
Site2
Site3
Site3
Site4
Site4




Team1
1
7
6
10
5
6


Team2
4
4
9
4
5
9


Team3
7
10
7
9
6
6


Team4
2
4
2
9
9
7



This same process seems to work for other tables I have. I don't understand.
Any suggestion is appreciated :)
Thank you

I was able to resolve the problem.
The issue was that the column Site corrected was sorted by the column Site_ID
So if you ever run into this problem check the Sort by column option in the Table view.

Go to Table view.
Select the Column with the repeated values.
Click on the Sort by column and change the column sorted on

